# Little Endian vs. Big Endian architectures

Tags: memory, cpu-architecture, endianness, data-representation

I've a question it is a kind of disagreement with a university professor, about Endianness, So I did not find any mean to solve this and find the right answer but asking and open a discussion in Stack Overflow community.

Let's say that we have this number (hex)11FF1 defined as an integer,  for example in C++ it will be like : **int  num = 0x11FF1**, and ***I say*** that the number will be presented in the memory in a **little endian** machine as :

```
 addr[0] is f1   addr[1] is 1f   addr[2] is 01   addr[3] is 00
 in binary : 1111 0001   0001 1111   0000 0001   0000 0000
```

as the compiler considers **0x11ff1** as **0x0001ff1** and considers also **00** as the **1st byte** and **01** as the **2nd byte** and so on, and for the **Big Endian** I believe it will look like:

```
 addr[0] is 00   addr[1] is 01   addr[2] is 1f   addr[3] is f1
 in binary : 0000 0000   0000 0001   0001 1111   1111 0001
```

but he has another opinion, ***he says*** :

**Little Endian**

[image: Little Endian in the professor view]

**Big Endian**:

[image: Big Endian in the professor view]

> Actually I don't see anything logical in his representation, so I hope the developers Resolve this disagreement, Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would Like to announce that the professor had been completely responsive and corrected the examples above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hex and binary numbers are correct.

Your (professor's?) French image for little-endian makes no sense at all, none of the 3 representations are consistent with either of the other 2.

73713 is `0x11ff1` in hex, so there aren't any `0xFF` bytes (binary `11111111`).
In 32-bit little-endian, the bytes are `F1 1F 01 00` in order of increasing memory address.
You can get that by taking pairs of hex digits (bytes / octets) from the low end of the full hex value, then fill with zeros once you've consumed the value.

**It looks like they maybe padded the wrong side of the hex value with 0s to zero-extend to 32 bits as `0x11ff1000`, not `0x00011ff1`**.  Note these are full hex values of the whole number, not an attempt to break it down into separate hex bytes in any order.

But the hex and binary don't match each other; their binary *ends* with an all-ones byte, so it has `FF` as the high byte, not the 3rd byte.  I didn't check if that matches their hex in PDP (mixed) endian.

They broke up their hex column into 4 byte-sized groups, which would seem to indicate that it's showing bytes in memory order.  But that column is the same between their big- and little-endian images, so apparently that's not what they're doing, and they really did just extend it to 32 bits by left shifting (padding with low instead of high zero).

Also, the binary field in the big vs. little endian aren't the reverse of each other.  To flip from big to little endian, you reverse the order of the bytes within the integer, keeping each byte value the same.  (like x86 `bswap`).  Their `11111111` (FF) byte is 2nd in their big-endian version, but last in little-endian.

TL:DR: unfortunately, nothing about those images makes *any* sense that I can see.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Peter Cordes

Comment: @OmarGhannou: If this answered your question, please mark it accepted with the checkmark under the vote arrows.  And BTW, feel free to link your professor this answer.  I tried to phrase it so you could do that, just talking about the technical details.